# how to serve wp-content/uploads folder of wordpress site from GSC Bucket?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am currently hosting my website on a VPS. The VPS storage is decreasing day by day as my website is currently serving a lof of pdf files.

I uoload website's wp-content/uploads folder to GCS bucekt and thought that plugins can easily serve all of the media from the bucket. But unfortunately, all the plugins put images of media gallery from the server to the bucket, even the free plugins do not migrate old existing images from the server to the bucket.

How I can serve my entire wp-content/uploads folder from GSC instead of VPS server?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.htaccess` file in the WordPress root directory and redirect from `wp-content/uploads` to the Cloud Storage URL. This is easier/faster than writing a plugin to rewrite each document. Otherwise, you will need to purchase a plugin with that feature.

This line redirects all requests to items in the 2018 folder to the equivalent cloud storage location. I am using a custom domain name for storage + CDN. Use one redirect for each folder under `uploads`. Do not redirect `uploads` as plugins also use that folder location for sensitive data stores (backups, etc).

```
Redirect 307 /wp-content/uploads/2018 https://cdn.jhanley.com/data/wp-content/uploads/2018
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can I make GCS Bucket writeable for the plugin? My pdf(s) are in a plugin folder in uploads.

Comment: @FahimSiddiq - I don't understand your question. Post a new question with details.

Comment: I tried your solution but the redirect is not working, I appreciate it if you tell/send/forward me the actual steps

Comment: @FahimSiddiq - ***is not working** is not a good problem description. What is not working? Use the CLI `curl` to debug redirects. Edit your question with details.